# How to change the value of a cell in an ASP.NET table using C# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to be able to use the code behind to set the value of a cell in a table

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CellPadding="10"
GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="Cornsilk">
<asp:TableRow ID="Row1">
<asp:TableCell ID="Cell1"></asp:TableCell>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it `runat=server`:

```
<asp:TableCell runat="server" ID="Cell1"></asp:TableCell>
```

and you can access it from codebehind directly:

```
Cell1.Text = "New Value";
```

otherwise you can access it via `Rows` and `Cells` of the table:

```
Table1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "New Value";
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to set the value in table cell dynamically

```
for (int i = 0; i <= this.Table1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        TableCell tc = this.Table1.Rows[i].FindControl("Cell1") as TableCell;
        if (tc != null)
        {
            tc.Text = "New Value";
        }
    }
```